# How to upload the modelandview to Azure blob storage in spring boot

Tags: azure, azure-storage, modelandview

I am new to Azure and I want to upload modelandview excel file to azure blob storage. Please help me how to upload modelandview file.

Comment: Currently the excel file is downloaded in local, want to store the excel in azure blob for sometime and then download the excel file.

Comment: I will try and let you the details. sorry for late reply.

Comment: It worked for me.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just navigate to the storage account in the azure portal, create a container and upload the excel file.

Refer to : [Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal)

Comment: One more question is how will pass the downloaded excel file to UI?Any suggestions.

Comment: @AMani What do you mean `pass the downloaded excel file to UI`?